# Starting watchOS, can't fit 2 pickers side by side

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-simulator

While trying out watchKit and watchOS, for the first time, to make a small app, I have this issue.
I cannot fit 2 WKInterfacePicker objects beside each other.
Eventhough I made them narrow enough, it doesn't seem to fit. They always come back one on top of the other. I did not find any way to include 2 components in the picker either.
What is the secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the secret I found to solve my problem, I hope it may help someone else who may have the same issue.

Inside `Interface.storyboard`, there is a component called `Group`. If you use it you will be able to put the pickers, side by side, inside it.

At the time I am writing I have only tried 2 `WKInterfacePicker` objects, and only in the simulator.